# using .htaccess to redirect .asp to .php?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, 301-redirect, asp.net

Ahoy all! I've been racking my brain with this one.

I basically just converted all of my pages from ASP code to PHP code. Kept the same filenames.

So, here is the htaccess code I have so far, but it keeps redirecting to my ROOT.... ie /home/accountname/publc_html...

What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.asp $1.php [R=301]
```

Comment: "Kept the same filenames." - So your PHP files are actually "filename.asp"?

Comment: @w3d That's obviously not what he meant. Same file name, new extension.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I kept the filenames but changed the extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding a slash before the target url ($1) like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ /$1.php [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Well, this was it, except backward!! RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ /$1.php [R=301]

Comment: hah thanks for pointing that out, not sure how I missed that one. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.asp [nc]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmmm... that actually didn't do anything. It isn't redirecting at all.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Appreciate the help! Linux. I tried with both the NC and the R=301.   With the 301, it seems to redirect to the ROOT. For example, it will redirect from http://www.sitename.com/name.asp  to http://www.sitename.com/home/accountname/name.php.  Weird!

Comment: @PaulHanak is there any other rewrites in your .htaccess would you please paste the entire file if so.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. The only other rewrite in the htaccess is for hidding hidden files and directories as per the boiler plate.   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]   I have also placed your code at the very top of my htaccess file if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP on IIS and know that you don't have any .asp pages left over you can add a handler for IIS to interpret .asp pages as PHP.  This is just a neat trick that masks the fact that you are actually running PHP.

@anagio's rewrite rule will work.  Make sure its a permanent redirect by adding the appropriate header.

Comment: in Apache you can make .asp work as .php with an AddHandler rule like AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .asp (or /x-httpd-php5 depending on how the php handler is defined)

Answer (score -1):

try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1.php [nc]
```